# Deployment scenario of git integrated Azure Data Factory via arm template

Tags: deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

What happens if you have multiple features being tested in test environment of a ADF V2 test data factory and only one or few of them is ready for production deployment. How do we hande this type of deployment scenario in Microsoft recommended CICD model of git/vsts integrated adf v2 through arm template

Consider we have dev test and prod environment of ADF v2. The dev environment is git integrated. The developers have debuged their changes and merged with collaboration​ branch after pull request. The changes are published and deployed to test environment first. Here many features are getting tested but few are ready for prod and few are not, how do we move the ones which are ready since tge arm template takes the entire factory?

Comment: can anyone share anything on this?

Comment: For me, it's all about GIT repository and the way how you manage your branches. ADF should be deployed as a whole. If you deployed some features which not ready for Production - a developer should revert it back in the code repository to make it ready for production. The scenario that you are describing sounds like experimental ADF. In that case, you might want to use either separate branch for developers and test it before the code comes to collaboration branch or separate ADF at all. It's all up to you - find the best solution for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

this is somewhat of a strange question. you can apply same logic to anything, how do you create a feature for an application since application is only deployed as a single entity. answer would be: use git flow or something akin to that. Use feature branches and promotions.

Comment: its not always a whole app for eg. you may start of your ADF building a pipeline for a copy activity to pull data from source A to sink B and deploy to test and prod. Later you may have req come up for onboarding new source sink copy pipelines and your developers may work individually on these reqs. So they may be testing multiple such pielines in the same ADF test env however only few of them may be ready for deployment to production and that is challenging with the current way of ADF v2 depoyment through ARM template since it always deploys the entire factory and not specific pipelines.